# (SyntaxError): Out of memory number

Tags: javascript, gwt, web-applications

A user reported this error from one of our Java web-apps with lots of GWT (thus Javascript).

[image]

I have never seen this error before, and am unable to replicate it, and Googling has revealed nothing. I know for sure that this error message isn't in our code (I examined every instance of the word "memory" in our source). Has anyone got a clue as to what this might mean?

Comment: what does it say in details? How often does your user experience it? Can it be reproduced?

Comment: So far it's a one off and the user dismissed the dialog without looking at details.